# Merge filters in a pivot table (Excel)

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, merge, combine

I have a very simple pivot table that has multiple filters.

Example of source worksheet:

[Pivot table source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdONC.png)

The pivot table just lists all the Employee names (e.g. Employee A) and provides 5 filters for the dates, for example:

[Pivot table fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuO2l.png)

[Pivot table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OIZH.png)

If I choose a date from one of the filters it will show me the Employees that use that date.

However as the filters are the same data type I would like to combine these filters into one.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may use the Power Query to hanlde your previous data.

1. Right click your table > Get Data from Table/Range.
2. Select the first column, go to Transform > Unpivot Other Columns.
   [image]
3. Rename the headers, such as "Week" and "Date" as the following screenshot shown. Besides, click the icon to change the data format as Date.
   [image]
4. Click File > Close and Load to, load the tabel to your previous workbook.
5. Create a pivot table, then there is a new field "Date", please check whether it is your needs.
   [image]

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much Emily for this. Works perfectly! Never used "Unpivot Columns" before :)

Answer (score 0):

*Considering data orientation of source data only one possibility is left to fix the issue, another is Formula based solution.*

**Before:**

[image]

**After:**

[image]

---

- For Pivot Table design, put Employees in Rows and Dates as Filter.

[image]

**N.B.**

- *In source data enter an appropriate Header to Employee's name, since Excel never considers data without Header.*

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm already using my fields in a similar way to your example. Not sure how this would consolidate my filters. I've updated my original question with screenshots.

Comment: @Rubio,, I've suggested what was the mere possible,, now let me check the new screenshot,,, !

Comment: @Rubio,,, Considering your screen shot nothing wrong, is the only possible, U are getting Count for users on DOW,, is always 1, because each DOW has similar date,, another I've tried copied the source data & used TRANSPOSE then used Transposed data set for PT,, have Weekdays in Filter and use COUNT for Users,,!! Try this and let me know,, or post the expected output, I'll try something different!